# how to extract properties of a list object and passing into stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, object, model-view-controller

I have a model class Employee

```
public class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Designation { get; set; }
        public string Department { get; set; }
        public DateTime Dateofjoin { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public int IsActive { get; set; }
        public int row_number { get; set; }

    }
```

and another model class having list object of Employee model class along with another property

```
 public class EmployeeList
    {
        public IList<Employee> Emp_List { get; set; }
        public int Return_Param { get; set; }
    }
```

I have a Database call method and the input to that method is the object of EmployeeList model class. I would like to pass each property of Emp_List in EmployeeList model class as parameters to the stored procedure. here is the code

```
  public int Edit_Employee(EmployeeList emp)
        {

            try
            {               
                if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                    con.Open();

                IList<Employee> newlist = new List<Employee>();
                newlist = emp.Emp_List;

                using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
                {
                    SqlParameter RETURN_VALUE_OUTPUT = new SqlParameter();
                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.CommandText = "dbo.Proc_PIP_Employee";
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Flag", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 3;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Empid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = newlist.Id;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 500).Value =;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Designation", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = ;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Department", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = ;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DateofJoin", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = ;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Phone", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = ;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Isactive", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ;
```

newlist.Id gives error like  doesnt contain definition for Id. How do I pass each property of Emp_List as stored procedure parameter?

Comment: A *list* is *zero, one, or many* instances of some type (`Employee` here); do you want to call `Proc_PIP_Employee` once per `Employee`? or...? note: it isn't the *list* that has the `Id` - it is each of the successive objects *in* the list

Comment: do you want to send emp id of any specific employee? is there any condition to get this employee? or do you want to send all employee ids to the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *seems* like you're simply missing a `foreach`:

```cs
foreach (var emp in emp.Emp_List)
{
    // ... blah ...
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Empid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = emp.Id;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 500).Value = emp.Name;
    // ... blah ...
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```